# Как создать самописный сайт для тестирования?

Tags: php, тестирование

Где можно найти видеоуроки или блоги где есть примеры самописного сайта для тестирования знаний студента? Было задано сделать сайт без движка (фреймворка), а то создал бы за час wordpress+testme, но увы нельзя. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: @Madi, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся.

Отдельно выделю

> для тестирования знаний студента

Comment: вот сайт на php,
    

    <html><head></head><body>
    <?php
    echo "Hello World";
    ?></body></html>

пользуйтесь на здоровье.

Comment: @eicto :) Все изучение сводится к некоторым мелочам и обычной магии, особенно начальном этапе.

1)__wakeup();

2) file_get_contents();

3) __clone();

4)!$result

5) file_get_contents();

6) __clone();

7)$result

8) __sleep();

9) production

))

А если серьезно, то море книг в интернете! Да и скриптов готовых море. 

http://www.script-php.ru/script_testov/ (первое что попалось)

Да и попробуйте задать этот вопрос google.

Comment: @Victor Halauko не понял, как этот коммент ко мне относится :) я как бы намекал что "сайт" понятие весьма абстрактное.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если хотите просто сдать, но не знать - скачайте любой скрипт c Google ("примеры программ на PHP").

Если же хотите разобраться - прочитайте [это руководство для начинающих Web разработчиков](http://noob.onthe.io/). Там поймете - как все настроить, сделать сайт и даже навернуть какие-то крутые функции. Если засадите - за день сможете что-то базовое сделать.